# Limiting top rows in

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm new to Stackoverflow, and I'm pretty new to MSSQL too (I've been using MYSQL for a couple of years now), and I was wondering if anyone could please help me with a query I'm having trouble with?
I've made a story archive page for a site that I'm putting together, and it's working fine, but the only problem is that I want to archive everything except for the top 6 stories in my table.

I came across a piece of code which will ignore the top few results (6 in my case), but I'm a little bit stumped as to how to incorporate it into my query. 
I've tried a few things but I keep getting error messages - I think I'm way off track.
Any help that anyone can give me would be hugely appreciated!

Thank you very much in advance:)

This is the query I found:

```
SELECT *
FROM PageContent 
WHERE id NOT IN (
         SELECT TOP 6 id 
         FROM PageContent 
         ORDER BY date)
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER by PageId desc) AS RowNum
  FROM PageContent WHERE pagestory_type = 'latest_news'
) AS MyDerivedTable
WHERE MyDerivedTable.RowNum BETWEEN $qpage_srt and $qpage_fin ORDER by date desc";
```

Comment: Have u done any workout?????.. if yes please share it...

Answer (score 1):

If you have SQL Server 2012 you can try:

```
SELECT *
FROM PageContent 
ORDER BY [date] 
OFFSET 6 ROWS
```

Comment: Thank you very much guys for all of your help, I really appreciate it! That worked perfectly thank you wdosanjos:) It's a nice and easy fix that makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much to everyone else for your help and suggestions too, I'll give them all a try, it's great to know as many methods as possible. Thank you all very much again:)

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just use the TOP clause with a select from the table ordered by the column you need?  Similar to the sample you found.

```
SELECT TOP X * -- add fields as needed 
FROM   PageContent 
WHERE  pagestory_type = 'latest_news'
ORDER  BY PageId DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont find any difference in your query except the parameter variables

`$qpage_srt and $qpage_fin`

it should be `@qpage_srt and @qpage_fin` in Ms sql...